# SQLite сумма со столбцов по уникальному значению поля C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite

В БД существует подобная таблица.

| ID | key | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.13 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.15 | 2.5 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.55 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 0.63 | 2.22 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Возможно ли как-то составить запрос, чтобы в ответе были возвращены значения по уникалькому полю **key**, а значения полей **value1** и **value2** были просуммированы? Смотрите пример желаемого ответа на запрос ниже:

| ID | key | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| * | 1 | 0.28 | 3.5 |
| * | 2 | 1.18 | 2.22 |

Comment: Можно. Составляйте. Придётся использовать GROUP BY + SUM(). PS. 0.13+0.15=0.28, вроде как...

Comment: @Akina Вроде получилось... Спасибо